# Debian Stretch won't resolve hostname, but IP works

Tags: debian, networking

I have configured Stretch networking for eth0 (it picked ens3), after setting:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
reboot
```

so now I have:

```
>: cat /etc/network/interfaces
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10/24
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

which works, so:

```
>: ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:0a:f7:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe0a:f7bc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And I can ping google nameservers like:

```
>: ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=10.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=10.9 ms
```

But not google itself, or any other domain. My hosts file looks like:

```
>: cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.10    someserver.name.com someserver

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My resolv.conf looks like:

```
>: cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

but I can ping my gateway so the default route seems okay:

```
>: ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 onlink
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.10
```

my /etc/nsswitch.conf says:

```
hosts:          files dns
networks:       files
```

What is missing? Should I be doing something else in Stretch?

Comment: Please show `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` in your question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be confusing two issues routing and DNS. 
If you are able to ping numerical addresses, like <8.8.8.8> or <128.171.224.100> (www.hawaii.edu) then the issue is DNS, not routing.

The /etc/nsswitch.conf file specifies where to look for DNS information, and in what order to make the queries.  Look for the line strating with 'hosts'.

Comment: I wanted to verify routing before chasing down DNS issues. my /etc/nsswitch.conf says `hosts: files dns`.

Comment: I ran `host google.com` and it returned `google.com has address 216.58.193.78` so that works. I tried disabling ipv6 too (someone said that helped) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10/24
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Remove the /24.
Reasons for this:
Syntax wise you're incorrect.

Assuming your 192.168.1.10 address contains a DNS server, removing the /24 should fix your error.

Comment: the /24 was put there by Stretch installer. I removed the CIDR and put `netmask 255.255.255.0` on the next line like Jessie, and it didn't help. The output of `ip a` is still the same, and looks right or routing wouldn't work I think.

Comment: The CIDR syntax is accepted since wheezy at least. And the OP clearly does not run a resolver on the host.